# How to wrap a <TransactionDetail> tag around my element sets?

Tags: xml, xslt

The following is my XML. I added the needed tags as a comment. I need to add a  tag before every  element and containing all elements up to  in each transaction.

```
<Transactions>
 <!--TransactionDetail-->
  <Number>63400</Number>
  <Title>Interest Expense</Title>
  <Type>Check</Type>
  <Date>2017-05-04</Date>
  <Name>Dell Financial Services</Name>
  <Memo>003-8922605-001</Memo>
  <Split>MCM BofA Checking</Split>
  <Amount>160</Amount>
  <Balance>160</Balance>
  <Number>Total 63400</Number>
  <Title>Interest Expense</Title>
  <Amount>160</Amount>
  <Balance>160</Balance>
 <!--/TransactionDetail>-->
 <!--TransactionDetail-->
  <Number>64000</Number>
  <Title>Internet Expenses</Title>
  <Type>Bill</Type>
  <Date>2017-05-29</Date>
  <Name>Swift Systems, Inc.</Name>
  <Memo>Server Hosting Fee</Memo>
  <SplitNum>20000</SplitNum>
  <SplitTitle>Accounts Payable</SplitTitle>
  <Amount>250</Amount>
  <Balance>250</Balance>
  <Number>Total 64000</Number>
  <Title>Internet Expenses</Title>
  <Amount>250</Amount>
  <Balance>250</Balance>
 <!--/TransactionDetail>-->
 <!--TransactionDetail-->
  <Number>64500</Number>
  <Title>Client Expenses</Title>
 .....
```

I am new to XML and XSLT.

[image]

Comment: Deleted in the question but need a tag before every number element and after every balance element. That entails a "set" of data in this account.

Comment: Try any text book on XSLT (like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm) and see the section/chapter on grouping flat information respectively the use of  `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with` or even see the spec section "Example: Identifying a Group by its Initial Element" in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples

Comment: You say 'need a tag before every number element and after every balance element. That entails a "set" of data in this account' but in the sample you have `<Number>63400</Number>` and `<Number>Total 63400</Number>` and only the first of those two is wrapped by `TransactionDetail`. So how do you want the XSLT code to distinguish between those two `Number` elements, how for the two `Balance` (`<Balance>160</Balance>` and `<Balance>160</Balance>`)?

Comment: Couldn't I change my select value for the second occurrence of number and balance using an XPath select of following::Number and following::Balance and just change the wrapping tag to something like <TotalNumber> and <TotalBalance> to distinguish those values?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Transactions">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Number[ position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <TransactionDetail>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </TransactionDetail>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
Try it
```

Comment: Hey apologies again for not being clear but is this XSLT 2.0? I am currently only working with v1.0. Thanks

Comment: I reuploaded and edited this question with more detail if anyone wants to take a look. Added my XML, XSLT, output XML, and desired XML for a better idea of what i need. Thanks!